# How to add response headers with HAproxy 1.6 based on request URI?

Tags: haproxy, cache, http-headers

I use HAproxy 1.6 as load balancer in front of tomcat servers.

I need to add response headers based on the request URI.

For e.g., I'd like to add the response header `Cache-Control public,max-age="600"` when the request uri is `/api` but not when the request uri is something else.

- My first try was using acl based on path to add the headers to http-response:

  ```
  acl api path_reg ^/api/(.*)$
  http-response add-header Cache-Control public,max-age="600" if api
  ```

  When I start haproxy with `-d`, I have warning saying that `path_reg` (or `path`) is incompatible with `http-response`:

  ```
  Dec  6 15:22:29 ip-10-30-0-196 haproxy-systemd-wrapper[315]: 
  [WARNING] 340/152229 (2035) : parsing 
  [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:78] : acl 'api' will never match because 
  it only involves keywords that are incompatible with 'backend 
  http-response header rule'
  ```
- I tried to add the header in `http-request` instead of `http-response`:

  ```
  acl api path_reg ^/api/(.*)$
  http-request add-header Cache-Control public,max-age="600" if api
  ```

  That worked but I need it in the response
- I also tried to use haproxy variables:

  ```
  http-request set-var(txn.path) path
  acl path_acl %[var(txn.path)] -m ^/api/(.*)$
  http-response add-header Cache-Control public,max-age="600" if path_acl
  ```

  But when I try HAproxy doesn't event start and I have the following error:

  ```
  [ALERT] 340/162647 (2241) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:48] 
  : error detected while parsing ACL 'path_acl' : unknown fetch 
  method '%[var' in ACL expression '%[var(txn.path)]'.
  ```

How can I use the request path into an acl to set the response header?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
http-response set-header Cache-Control no-cache,\ max-age=600 if { capture.req.uri -m beg /api/ }
```

`capture.req.uri` persists until the response is processed, unlike `path`, which does not.

A few notes:

This example uses an anonymous ACL.  You could also do it with a named ACL, but that takes 2 lines.

There is no reason I am aware of why you should quote the max-age value.

You probably don't want to `add-header`, you want to `set-header`, which ensures that if one is already present, it will be removed.

`acl path_acl %[var(txn.path)] -m ^/api/(.*)$` is probably correctly written as `acl path_acl var(txn.path) -m ^/api/(.*)$`.  HAProxy is a little finicky about when it expects `%[ ]` and when it doesn't.  I'm sure there's a pattern, but I'm not clear just what is is.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Both method using `capture.req.uri` and variables while removing `%[ ]` in `acl̀` are working. You're also right about the quotes around `max-age` value and the `set-header` instead of `add-header`.

Comment: Note that internally, I do something similar, if the back-end does not provide a `Cache-Control` response: I add a `Cache-Control-Authority: implicit, gateway` header to give the developer/troubleshooter/tester a heads-up that I, the proxy, am providing that header, not the application, but the app can disable me by simply providing its own header.  Note this header is nothing standard -- I just made it up, to help others on the team be aware that I was providing this in-line, not the app.  The proxies are so trouble-free that they have a bad habit of forgetting they are in the path at all.